TypeError: empty() received an invalid combination of arguments
I want to do object detection using cascade r-cnn and swin transformer. Here is my code and the libraries I installed.
mmcv                           2.1.0
mmdet                          3.3.0               /content/mmdetection
mmengine                       0.10.5
torch                          2.1.0
torchaudio                     2.1.0
torchsummary                   1.5.1
torchvision                    0.16.0

cascade_rcnn_swin_small_patch4_window7_mstrain_480-800_giou_4conv1f_adamw_3x_PROJECT_NAME.py

_base_ = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/cascade_rcnn_swin_small_patch4_window7_mstrain_480-800_giou_4conv1f_adamw_3x_coco.py'

model = dict(
    roi_head=dict(
        bbox_head=[
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_classes=4),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_classes=4),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_classes=4)]))


dataset_type = 'COCODataset'

classes = ('Coccolith-PPL', 'Coccolith-XPL', 'Discoaster-PPL', 'Discoaster-XPL')

data = dict(
    train=dict(
        img_prefix='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/train/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/annotation/train.json'),
    val=dict(
        img_prefix='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/valid/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/annotation/val.json'),
    test=dict(
        img_prefix='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/test/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/dataset/annotation/test.json'))

load_from = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/checkpoints/cascade_mask_rcnn_swin_small_patch4_window7.pth'`

cascade_rcnn_swin_fpn.py
#from mmcv.cnn import MODELS

model = dict(
    type='CascadeRCNN',
    #pretrained=None,
    backbone=dict(
        type='SwinTransformer',
        embed_dims=96,
        depths=[2, 2, 6, 2],
        num_heads=[3, 6, 12, 24],
        window_size=7,
        mlp_ratio=4.,
        qkv_bias=True,
        qk_scale=None,
        drop_rate=0.,
        attn_drop_rate=0.,
        drop_path_rate=0.2,
        #ape=False,
        patch_norm=True,
        out_indices=(0, 1, 2, 3),
        #use_checkpoint=False
        ),
    neck=dict(
        type='FPN',
        in_channels=[96, 192, 384, 768],
        out_channels=256,
        num_outs=5),
    rpn_head=dict(
        type='RPNHead',
        in_channels=256,
        feat_channels=256,
        anchor_generator=dict(
            type='AnchorGenerator',
            scales=[8],
            ratios=[0.5, 1.0, 2.0],
            strides=[4, 8, 16, 32, 64]),
        bbox_coder=dict(
            type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
            target_means=[.0, .0, .0, .0],
            target_stds=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]),
        loss_cls=dict(
            type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=True, loss_weight=1.0),
        loss_bbox=dict(type='SmoothL1Loss', beta=1.0 / 9.0, loss_weight=1.0)),
    roi_head=dict(
        type='CascadeRoIHead',
        num_stages=3,
        stage_loss_weights=[1, 0.5, 0.25],
        bbox_roi_extractor=dict(
            type='SingleRoIExtractor',
            roi_layer=dict(type='RoIAlign', output_size=7, sampling_ratio=0),
            out_channels=256,
            featmap_strides=[4, 8, 16, 32]),
        bbox_head=[
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                in_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]),
                reg_class_agnostic=True,
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss',
                    use_sigmoid=False,
                    loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='SmoothL1Loss', beta=1.0,
                               loss_weight=1.0)),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                in_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1]),
                reg_class_agnostic=True,
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss',
                    use_sigmoid=False,
                    loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='SmoothL1Loss', beta=1.0,
                               loss_weight=1.0)),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                in_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.033, 0.033, 0.067, 0.067]),
                reg_class_agnostic=True,
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss',
                    use_sigmoid=False,
                    loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='SmoothL1Loss', beta=1.0, loss_weight=1.0))
        ]),
    #model training and testing settings
    train_cfg = dict(
        rpn=dict(
            assigner=dict(
                type='MaxIoUAssigner',
                pos_iou_thr=0.7,
                neg_iou_thr=0.3,
                min_pos_iou=0.3,
                match_low_quality=True,
                ignore_iof_thr=-1),
            sampler=dict(
                type='RandomSampler',
                num=256,
                pos_fraction=0.5,
                neg_pos_ub=-1,
                add_gt_as_proposals=False),
            allowed_border=0,
            pos_weight=-1,
            debug=False),
        rpn_proposal=dict(
            nms_across_levels=False,
            nms_pre=2000,
            nms_post=2000,
            max_per_img=2000,
            nms=dict(type='nms', iou_threshold=0.7),
            min_bbox_size=0),
        rcnn=[
            dict(
                assigner=dict(
                    type='MaxIoUAssigner',
                    pos_iou_thr=0.5,
                    neg_iou_thr=0.5,
                    min_pos_iou=0.5,
                    match_low_quality=False,
                    ignore_iof_thr=-1),
                sampler=dict(
                    type='RandomSampler',
                    num=512,
                    pos_fraction=0.25,
                    neg_pos_ub=-1,
                    add_gt_as_proposals=True),
                pos_weight=-1,
                debug=False),
            dict(
                assigner=dict(
                    type='MaxIoUAssigner',
                    pos_iou_thr=0.6,
                    neg_iou_thr=0.6,
                    min_pos_iou=0.6,
                    match_low_quality=False,
                    ignore_iof_thr=-1),
                sampler=dict(
                    type='RandomSampler',
                    num=512,
                    pos_fraction=0.25,
                    neg_pos_ub=-1,
                    add_gt_as_proposals=True),
                pos_weight=-1,
                debug=False),
            dict(
                assigner=dict(
                    type='MaxIoUAssigner',
                    pos_iou_thr=0.7,
                    neg_iou_thr=0.7,
                    min_pos_iou=0.7,
                    match_low_quality=False,
                    ignore_iof_thr=-1),
                sampler=dict(
                    type='RandomSampler',
                    num=512,
                    pos_fraction=0.25,
                    neg_pos_ub=-1,
                    add_gt_as_proposals=True),
                pos_weight=-1,
                debug=False)
        ]),
    test_cfg = dict(
        rpn=dict(
            nms_across_levels=False,
            nms_pre=1000,
            nms_post=1000,
            max_per_img=1000,
            nms=dict(type='nms', iou_threshold=0.7),
            min_bbox_size=0),
        rcnn=dict(
            score_thr=0.05,
            nms=dict(type='nms', iou_threshold=0.5),
            max_per_img=100)))

cascade_rcnn_swin_small_patch4_window7_mstrain_480-800_giou_4conv1f_adamw_3x_coco.py
_base_ = [
    '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SwinXCascade/configs/cascade_rcnn_swin_fpn.py',
    '/content/mmdetection/configs/_base_/datasets/coco_detection.py',
    '/content/mmdetection/configs/_base_/schedules/schedule_1x.py', '/content/mmdetection/configs/_base_/default_runtime.py'
]


model = dict(
    backbone=dict(
        embed_dims=96,
        depths=[2, 2, 18, 2],
        num_heads=[3, 6, 12, 24],
        window_size=7,
        #ape=False,
        drop_path_rate=0.2,
        patch_norm=True,
        #use_checkpoint=False
    ),
    neck=dict(in_channels=[96, 192, 384, 768]),
    roi_head=dict(
        bbox_head=[
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_shared_convs=4,
                num_shared_fcs=1,
                in_channels=256,
                conv_out_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]),
                reg_class_agnostic=False,
                reg_decoded_bbox=True,
                norm_cfg=dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True),
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='GIoULoss', loss_weight=10.0)),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_shared_convs=4,
                num_shared_fcs=1,
                in_channels=256,
                conv_out_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1]),
                reg_class_agnostic=False,
                reg_decoded_bbox=True,
                norm_cfg=dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True),
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='GIoULoss', loss_weight=10.0)),
            dict(
                type='Shared2FCBBoxHead',
                num_shared_convs=4,
                num_shared_fcs=1,
                in_channels=256,
                conv_out_channels=256,
                fc_out_channels=1024,
                roi_feat_size=7,
                num_classes=80,
                bbox_coder=dict(
                    type='DeltaXYWHBBoxCoder',
                    target_means=[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    target_stds=[0.033, 0.033, 0.067, 0.067]),
                reg_class_agnostic=False,
                reg_decoded_bbox=True,
                norm_cfg=dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True),
                loss_cls=dict(
                    type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=1.0),
                loss_bbox=dict(type='GIoULoss', loss_weight=10.0))
        ]))

img_norm_cfg = dict(
    mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53], std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375], to_rgb=True)

train_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(type='LoadAnnotations', with_bbox=True),
    dict(type='RandomFlip', flip_ratio=0.5),
    dict(type='AutoAugment',
         policies=[
             [
                 dict(type='Resize',
                      img_scale=[(480, 1333), (512, 1333), (544, 1333), (576, 1333),
                                 (608, 1333), (640, 1333), (672, 1333), (704, 1333),
                                 (736, 1333), (768, 1333), (800, 1333)],
                      multiscale_mode='value',
                      keep_ratio=True)
             ],
             [
                 dict(type='Resize',
                      img_scale=[(400, 1333), (500, 1333), (600, 1333)],
                      multiscale_mode='value',
                      keep_ratio=True),
                 dict(type='RandomCrop',
                      crop_type='absolute_range',
                      crop_size=(384, 600),
                      allow_negative_crop=True),
                 dict(type='Resize',
                      img_scale=[(480, 1333), (512, 1333), (544, 1333),
                                 (576, 1333), (608, 1333), (640, 1333),
                                 (672, 1333), (704, 1333), (736, 1333),
                                 (768, 1333), (800, 1333)],
                      multiscale_mode='value',
                      override=True,
                      keep_ratio=True)
             ]
         ]),
    dict(type='Normalize', **img_norm_cfg),
    dict(type='Pad', size_divisor=32),
    dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),
    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img', 'gt_bboxes', 'gt_labels']),
]
data = dict(train=dict(pipeline=train_pipeline))

optimizer = dict(_delete_=True, type='AdamW', lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.999), weight_decay=0.05,
                 paramwise_cfg=dict(custom_keys={'absolute_pos_embed': dict(decay_mult=0.),
                                                 'relative_position_bias_table': dict(decay_mult=0.),
                                                 'norm': dict(decay_mult=0.)}))
lr_config = dict(step=[27, 33])
runner = dict(type='EpochBasedRunner', max_epochs=36)
"""
fp16 = None
optimizer_config = dict(
    type="DistOptimizerHook",
    update_interval=1,
    grad_clip=None,
    coalesce=True,
    bucket_size_mb=-1,
    use_fp16=True,
)

"""


Error Message:
I encountered the following error when running the training script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 121, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 110, in main
    runner = Runner.from_cfg(cfg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 462, in from_cfg
    runner = cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.model = self.build_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 836, in build_model
    model = MODELS.build(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/registry.py", line 570, in build
    return self.build_func(cfg, *args, **kwargs, registry=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 232, in build_model_from_cfg
    return build_from_cfg(cfg, registry, default_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 121, in build_from_cfg
    obj = obj_cls(**args)  # type: ignore
  File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/cascade_rcnn.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/two_stage.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.backbone = MODELS.build(backbone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/registry.py", line 570, in build
    return self.build_func(cfg, *args, **kwargs, registry=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 232, in build_model_from_cfg
    return build_from_cfg(cfg, registry, default_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 121, in build_from_cfg
    obj = obj_cls(**args)  # type: ignore
  File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/backbones/swin.py", line 617, in __init__
    stage = SwinBlockSequence(
  File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/backbones/swin.py", line 437, in __init__
    block = SwinBlock(
  File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/backbones/swin.py", line 349, in __init__
    self.ffn = FFN(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/utils/misc.py", line 395, in new_func
    output = old_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmcv/cnn/bricks/transformer.py", line 608, in __init__
    Linear(in_channels, feedforward_channels),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.weight = Parameter(torch.empty((out_features, in_features), **factory_kwargs))
TypeError: empty() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple, dtype=NoneType, device=NoneType), but expected one of:
 * (tuple of ints size, *, tuple of names names, torch.memory_format memory_format, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.memory_format memory_format, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)

I tried to adjust the version of the library I'm using, but it didn't solve the problem.
Could anyone help, please? Thanks in advance.
